# Can you rebind the movement keys?

Tags: pc, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

When I played through the demo of Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning, I could never figure out how to rebind the movement keys.  I prefer to use ESDF instead of the standard WASD, and while I was willing to adapt to WASD for the duration of the demo, I do not plan on purchasing the game unless I can use ESDF.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes.

You can. From the menu, simply select Options > Controls > Controls and you're met with this screen:

[image]

By default:

- F is Interact
- E is Quick Mana Potion

You'll have to remap *those* keys first, followed by remapping the movement keys in the following order:

- Right
- Down
- Left
- Up

For some reason, mapping in another order bugs everything to F, rendering you immobile. If you follow this pattern, however, it works just fine!

Comment: Thanks for publishing the magic order in which keys must be bound. It was highly aggravating to see them stick together. And a hearty poke in the eyeball of whichever intern cobbled together the broken keybindings menu.